# Animating view in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation, objectanimator

I want a `addressCard` to scroll down behind another `FirstRowCard` which are both fragments. I have the `addressCard` appear behind the other but it doesn't scroll down. I realise I have to use `Object Animator` and include a `View` in the arguments.

I was originally using:

```
View addressCard = (View) getView().findViewById(R.id.years_of_cooking_xp_cardView);
    ObjectAnimator addressCard_Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(addressCard, "translationY", 0f, 258f);
```

But the `addressCard` just appears with no animation. General architecture is `Main Activity` creates a fragment called `topRow_fragment`. In `topRow_fragment` I've created an interface so when a User clicks on a button, it creates the `addressCard` fragment that is displayed underneath the `topRow_fragment`. When the User clicks the button, the other fragments disappear and this works fine. I've commented out some parts that I intend on actualising but until the initial animation is completed, I'll ignore them.

I think I haven't correctly identified the `View` associated with the `addressCard` and consequently no animation is able to be shown. Any help would be great thanks,

Here's the class:

```
public class topRow_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

addressCard_fragment addressCard;
onTopLeftClicked mCallback;
int addressCardLaunch = 0;
String NextAddressCardAnimation = "SLIDE DOWN";
View layoutReturn;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    layoutReturn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstrow_fragment, container, false);
    ImageButton top_row_left_button = (ImageButton) layoutReturn.findViewById(R.id.imageLeft);
    top_row_left_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    return layoutReturn;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    addressCard = new addressCard_fragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id. Below_top_row_fragment_container, addressCard);

    View addressCard = (View) getView().findViewById(R.id.years_of_cooking_xp_cardView);
    ObjectAnimator addressCard_Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(addressCard, "translationY", 0f, 258f);

    //CardView addressCard_View = (CardView) getView().findViewById(R.id.years_of_cooking_xp_cardView);
    //ObjectAnimator addressCard_Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(addressCard_View, "translationY", 0f, 258f);

    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageLeft:
            if (addressCardLaunch == 0) {
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                moveSecondRowAfterClick(0);
                addressCard_Animator.setDuration(250);
                addressCard_Animator.start();
                moveSecondRowAfterClick(0);
                addressCardLaunch = 1;
            }

            else if (addressCardLaunch == 1) {
                switch (NextAddressCardAnimation) {

                    case "SLIDE DOWN":
                        NextAddressCardAnimation = "SLIDE UP";
                        moveSecondRowAfterClick(1);
                        //addressCard_Animator.setInterpolator(new SlideDownAnimationInterpolator());
                        //addressCard_Animator.setDuration(250);
                        //addressCard_Animator.start();
                        break;

                    case "SLIDE UP":
                        NextAddressCardAnimation = "SLIDE DOWN";
                        moveSecondRowAfterClick(0);
                        //addressCard_Animator.setDuration(250);
                        //addressCard_Animator.start();
                        break;
                }
            }
    }
}

public interface onTopLeftClicked {
    void moveSecondRow(int slidingAnimationStatus);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Activity a;
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        a = (Activity) context;

        try {
            mCallback = (onTopLeftClicked) a;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(a.toString() + " must implement onTopLeftClicked Interface");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mCallback = null;
    super.onDetach();
}

public void moveSecondRowAfterClick(int slidingAnimationStatus) {
    mCallback.moveSecondRow(slidingAnimationStatus);
}}
```

Update01: 
I included methods within the fragment class, slideUpAnimation and slideDownAnimation and this has resolved a `NullPointerException` that I had. Yet to successfully animate the `addressCard` upon initialisation or subsequent button clicks. This approach is more in line with encapsulation rather than calling the animations within the `topRow_fragment` class. I'm wondering if this could now relate to view constraints I've emplaced on the CardView in the respective XML file.

Main Activity XML where the fragments are called, both `topRow_fragment` and `addressCard`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bryanjordan.settingsr11.MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Below_top_row_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="367dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Above_top_row_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="367dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_row_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"></RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Update02: I've looked at how `slideDownAnimation` and `slideUpAnimation` work and these are both being called correctly but the `View` just isn't moving. This is clearly a problem regarding assignment - I think it stems from the way the fragments are called.

Firstly, `topRow_fragment` is called then when the User clicks on a button `below_topRow_fragment`is created. I've been looking at using:

```
View layoutTest = layoutReturn.findViewById(R.id.Below_top_row_fragment_container);
            View addressTestR2 = (View) layoutTest.findViewById(R.id.years_of_cooking_xp_cardView);
```

And having `NullPointerException` errors but this seems to be the right direction as I'd have to call the respective child fragments to get to the one I want before then assigning it.